# Ubuntu 16.04 Remmina - Unable to Connect to the Server

Tags: 16.04, remmina

I worked in Remmina almost one week but now i have an error - Unable to Connect to the Server, trying to connect to Windows Server 2016.
any idea?

Comment: Could be any network problem. You could test with `ping`, `mtr` and `nc` commands.

Comment: I have a ping all works fine. the problem was an in the remote desktop settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tap on search icon --> Allow remote access to your computer --> move to Remote tab --> unmark Allow connections only from computers running Remote Desktop with Network Level Authentication (recommended)

[See the Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqofE.jpg)

Comment: For Future cases please be sure you are trying to connect via TLS. If you dont know edit your connection, move to advanced and change to TLS.